# Apple Wallet Event Pass Appears on Lockscreen Outside MaxDistance Range

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, mobile-development, apple-wallet

I'm working on creating an Event Pass for Apple Wallet and have encountered a peculiar issue where the pass appears on the lockscreen even when I'm outside the specified `maxDistance` range. Below are the key settings I've configured in my `pass.json`:

- `maxDistance`: 10 (intending to restrict the pass to appear only when within 10 meters of the specified location)
- Event time range: Confirmed I'm within the timeframe leading up to the event.
- `semantics`: Configured with the correct semantics for an event pass.
- `latitude` and `longitude`: Set to the exact location of the event.

Despite these configurations, the pass unexpectedly appears on the lockscreen even when I'm not within the 10 meters radius around the specified `latitude` and `longitude`.

Here's the relevant section from my `pass.json` (omitted personal or sensitive information for privacy):

```
{
   "description":"Event Ticket",
   "formatVersion":1,
   "organizationName":"Organization",
   "passTypeIdentifier":"pass.reverse-url",
   "teamIdentifier":"teamIdentifier",
   "serialNumber":"7IPGMT",
   "maxDistance":50,
   "foregroundColor":"rgb(230, 230, 230)",
   "backgroundColor":"rgb(20, 20, 20)",
   "labelColor":"rgb(255, 255, 255)",
   "relevantDate":"2024-03-21T10:00:00+02:00",
   "expirationDate":"2024-03-21T20:00:00+02:00",
   "semantics":{
      "eventType":"PKEventTypeLivePerformance",
      "eventStartDate":"2024-03-21T10:00:00+02:00",
      "eventEndDate":"2024-03-21T20:00:00+02:00",
      "eventName":"Event NAme",
      "genre":"Drum&Bass",
      "venueName":"Venue Name",
      "venueEntrance":"Main Entrance",
      "venueRoom":"Main Room",
      "venueLocation":{
         "latitude":44.41371026824406698096936452202498912811279296875,
         "longitude":26.109162364004571799114273744635283946990966796875
      },
      "location":{
         "latitude":44.41371026824406698096936452202498912811279296875,
         "longitude":26.109162364004571799114273744635283946990966796875
      },
      "performerNames":[
         "test",
         "test2"
      ]
   },
   "locations":[
      {
         "latitude":44.41371026824406698096936452202498912811279296875,
         "longitude":26.109162364004571799114273744635283946990966796875,
         "relevantText":"Present this pass at the checkpoint along with your ID.",
         "semantics":{
            "venueName":"Venue Name",
            "venueEntrance":"Main Entrance",
            "venueRoom":"Main Room",
            "venueLocation":{
               "latitude":44.41371026824406698096936452202498912811279296875,
               "longitude":26.109162364004571799114273744635283946990966796875
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "barcode":{
      "message":"7IPGMT",
      "format":"PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
      "altText":"7IPGMT",
      "messageEncoding":"iso-8859-1"
   },
   "eventTicket":{
      "headerFields":[
         {
            "key":"eventDate",
            "label":"Event Date",
            "value":"21.03.2024",
            "semantics":{
               "eventStartDate":"2024-03-21T10:00:00+02:00",
               "eventEndDate":"2024-03-21T20:00:00+02:00"
            }
         }
      ],
      "primaryFields":[
         {
            "key":"eventName",
            "label":"Event",
            "value":"Main Act Name",
            "semantics":{
               "eventName":"Event Name",
               "performerNames":[
                  "test",
                  "test2"
               ]
            }
         }
      ],
      "secondaryFields":[
         {
            "key":"location",
            "label":"Location",
            "value":"Venue Name",
            "semantics":{
               "venueName":"Venue Name",
               "venueEntrance":"Main Entrance",
               "venueRoom":"Main Room",
               "venueLocation":{
                  "latitude":44.41371026824406698096936452202498912811279296875,
                  "longitude":26.109162364004571799114273744635283946990966796875
               }
            }
         }
      ],
      "auxiliaryFields":[
         {
            "key":"name",
            "label":"Name",
            "value":"FirsName LastName"
         },
         {
            "key":"eventEdition",
            "label":"Event Edition",
            "value":"Event Chapter"
         }
      ],
      "backFields":[
         {
            "key":"ticketNumber",
            "label":"Ticket Number",
            "value":"7IPGMT"
         },
         {
            "key":"name",
            "label":"Name",
            "value":"FirstName LastName"
         },
         {
            "key":"inviteType",
            "label":"Invitation Type",
            "value":"General Access"
         },
         {
            "key":"eventLocationAddress",
            "label":"Event Address",
            "value":"Constantin R\u0103dulescu-Motru 19-15",
            "semantics":{
               "venueName":"Venue Name",
               "venueLocation":{
                  "latitude":44.41371026824406698096936452202498912811279296875,
                  "longitude":26.109162364004571799114273744635283946990966796875
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**What I've Tried:**

- **Modifying Coordinates:** I adjusted the `latitude` and `longitude` values in the `pass.json` to various locations to test the distance sensitivity. I expected the pass to not appear on the lockscreen when these new locations were more than 10 meters away from my current position.
- **Changing `maxDistance`:** I experimented with different `maxDistance` values, ranging from very small (5 meters) to larger distances (50 meters), to see if there was a threshold at which the behavior changed.

**Expected Outcome:**

I anticipated that these changes would prevent the event pass from appearing on the lockscreen when I was outside the specified `maxDistance` from the event location, especially considering I was within the event's time range.

**Actual Result:**

Despite these adjustments, the pass continues to appear on my lockscreen whenever I am within the event's time range, regardless of my physical distance from the event location. This occurs even when I am clearly outside the set `maxDistance` range.

Comment: 10m is a very small radius. Particularly if you are indoors where gps accuracy will be reduced. The horizontal accuracy is [added](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666620) so if you have the best possible accuracy (which is 10m) then your radius will effectively be 20m.  If your horizontal accuracy is 50m then your radius will be 60m.